# Java use generic type in ResponseEntity passed as function parameter

Tags: java, spring, generics, resttemplate

I was trying to map response from API to a specific Class table, where Class is passed as an argument. I don't have problems with the same operation in ArrayList.

For example `fetchTestPhotos(url, PhotoDto.class)` should map response to `ResponseEntity<PhotoDto[]>`

I tried code below but it didn't work.

```
public <T> void fetchTestPhotos(String url, Class<T> type) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<T[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, T[].class);

        if (response.getStatusCode().value() != 200) {
            throw new CannotFetchData("Cannot fetch data from " + url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't use the parameter `type` passed to the method which already holds `Class<T>` which can be `PhotoDto.class` as you say. Just use this parameter:

```
ResponseEntity<T[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, type);
```

Moreover, your method returns `void` type and the `response` is unused. Change the signature and return the `response`.

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> fetchTestPhotos(String url, Class<T> type) {
    ....
    return response;
}
```

Finally, if you want to return `ResponseEntity<T[]>` with generic array, you have also to change the formal parameters. The `T` and `T[]` are not interchangeable.

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T[]>  fetchTestPhotos(String url, Class<T[]> type) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<T[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, type);

    if (response.getStatusCode().value() != 200) {
        throw new CannotFetchData("Cannot fetch data from " + url);
    }
    return response;
}
```